# Error:(16, 69) tensorflow/examples/android/jni/object_tracking/logging.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, object-detection

I am trying to develop android app which can detect and identify real time object. There is no error in gradle build but when I am trying to build **apk** it gives me following errors.

Checked the folder there are all files like logging.cc but can't understand why this giving me error.
Please help me.

> C:\Users\shubham\Pictures\Camera Roll\jni\object_tracking\logging.cc
>   Error:(16, 69) tensorflow/examples/android/jni/object_tracking/logging.h: No such
>   file or directory
>           Error:(16, 69) fatal error: tensorflow/examples/android/jni/object_tracking/logging.h: No such
>   file or directory

**The Code:**

```
/* Copyright 2017 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
==============================================================================*/

#include "tensorflow/examples/android/jni/object_tracking/logging.h"

#ifdef STANDALONE_DEMO_LIB

#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

LogMessage::LogMessage(const char* fname, int line, int severity)
    : fname_(fname), line_(line), severity_(severity) {}

void LogMessage::GenerateLogMessage() {
  int android_log_level;
  switch (severity_) {
    case INFO:
      android_log_level = ANDROID_LOG_INFO;
      break;
    case WARNING:
      android_log_level = ANDROID_LOG_WARN;
      break;
    case ERROR:
      android_log_level = ANDROID_LOG_ERROR;
      break;
    case FATAL:
      android_log_level = ANDROID_LOG_FATAL;
      break;
    default:
      if (severity_ < INFO) {
        android_log_level = ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE;
      } else {
        android_log_level = ANDROID_LOG_ERROR;
      }
      break;
  }

  std::stringstream ss;
  const char* const partial_name = strrchr(fname_, '/');
  ss << (partial_name != nullptr ? partial_name + 1 : fname_) << ":" << line_
     << " " << str();
  __android_log_write(android_log_level, "native", ss.str().c_str());

  // Also log to stderr (for standalone Android apps).
  std::cerr << "native : " << ss.str() << std::endl;

  // Android logging at level FATAL does not terminate execution, so abort()
  // is still required to stop the program.
  if (severity_ == FATAL) {
    abort();
  }
}

namespace {

// Parse log level (int64) from environment variable (char*)
int64_t LogLevelStrToInt(const char* tf_env_var_val) {
  if (tf_env_var_val == nullptr) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Ideally we would use env_var / safe_strto64, but it is
  // hard to use here without pulling in a lot of dependencies,
  // so we use std:istringstream instead
  std::string min_log_level(tf_env_var_val);
  std::istringstream ss(min_log_level);
  int64_t level;
  if (!(ss >> level)) {
    // Invalid vlog level setting, set level to default (0)
    level = 0;
  }

  return level;
}

int64_t MinLogLevelFromEnv() {
  const char* tf_env_var_val = getenv("TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL");
  return LogLevelStrToInt(tf_env_var_val);
}

int64_t MinVLogLevelFromEnv() {
  const char* tf_env_var_val = getenv("TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL");
  return LogLevelStrToInt(tf_env_var_val);
}

}  // namespace

LogMessage::~LogMessage() {
  // Read the min log level once during the first call to logging.
  static int64_t min_log_level = MinLogLevelFromEnv();
  if (TF_PREDICT_TRUE(severity_ >= min_log_level)) GenerateLogMessage();
}

int64_t LogMessage::MinVLogLevel() {
  static const int64_t min_vlog_level = MinVLogLevelFromEnv();
  return min_vlog_level;
}

LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(const char* file, int line)
    : LogMessage(file, line, ANDROID_LOG_FATAL) {}
LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() {
  // abort() ensures we don't return (we promised we would not via
  // ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN).
  GenerateLogMessage();
  abort();
}

void LogString(const char* fname, int line, int severity,
               const std::string& message) {
  LogMessage(fname, line, severity) << message;
}

void LogPrintF(const int severity, const char* format, ...) {
  char message[1024];
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr, format);
  vsnprintf(message, 1024, format, argptr);
  va_end(argptr);
  __android_log_write(severity, "native", message);

  // Also log to stderr (for standalone Android apps).
  std::cerr << "native : " << message << std::endl;
}

#endif
```